# Receving valgrind error on conditional jump

Tags: c, hashtable, valgrind

I got this code which creates a 3D ARRAY - more like a 2D array that each cell is a pointer. I'm trying to initialize it to be `LENGTH_OF_ROW * SIZE * sizeof(Node)`.

This is struct Node:

```
typedef struct Node
{
void * data;
void *key;
}Node;
```

and this is the code to creating a hash table:

```
 Node*** createHashTable(size_t size)
 {
 Node ***hashTable = (Node***)malloc(LENGTH_OF_ROW*sizeof(Node**));
 for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH_OF_ROW; i++)
 {
    hashTable[i] = (Node**)malloc(size * sizeof(Node*));
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)size; j++)
    {
        hashTable[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        hashTable[i][j]->key = EMPTY_CELL;
    }
}
return hashTable;
}
```

this is the valgrind error:

> 49427== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> 49427== at 0x4C28BCD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
>
> 49427==   by 0x400844: createHashTable (GenericHashTable.c:40)
>
> 49427==    by 0x40091B: createTable (GenericHashTable.c:57)
>
> 49427==    by 0x4015E5: main (HashIntSearch.c:30)

So an error at line 40, 
this line:  `hashTable[i] = (Node**)malloc(size * sizeof(Node*));`
Can't figure out why am I getting this error.

Thanks!

size is defined in main this way:

```
size_t tableSize;
int val;
sscanf(argv[1], "%d",(&tableSize));
sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &val);
// Creating a table with addresses of functions.
TableP table = createTable(tableSize, &cloneInt, &freeInt, &intFcn,
                                        &intPrint, &intPrint, &intCompare);
```

this is createTable:

```
TableP createTable(size_t tableSize, CloneKeyFcn cloneKey, FreeKeyFcn   freeKey
 , HashFcn hfun, PrintKeyFcn printKeyFun, PrintDataFcn printDataFun
, ComparisonFcn fcomp)
{
TableP table = (TableP)malloc(sizeof(Table));
table->multiplicity = 1;
table->originalSize = tableSize;
table->currentSize = tableSize;
table->hashTable = createHashTable(tableSize);
table->cloner = cloneKey;
table->freer = freeKey;
table->hash = hfun;
table->keyPrinter = printKeyFun;
table->dataPrinter = printDataFun;
table->comparer = fcomp;
return table;
}
```

I'm running valgrind with size 1

Comment: Please don't add line-numbers to code you show, it makes it hard to read, ad even harder to e.g. copy and try ourselves. Instead add e.g a comment in the code at the relevant line or lines.

Comment: Also, you don't really need a tripple-pointer here, [being a three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is usually not a compliment. Use just a  double-pointer, and in the innermost loop you don't need to allocate each node dynamically.

Comment: I tried to use double pointer but program had tons of errors and didn't even compile

Comment: Then fix the errors? Did you actually read the error messages? Did you attempt to use the arrow operator `->` to access members of the structure instead of the dot `.`?

Comment: As for your Valgrind error, how do you call this function? What is the value of `size`? What is `LENGTH_OF_ROW`?

Comment: Yes syntax was spot on, dot everywhere but I was getting an error I think it was like this: SYSMALLOC ASSERTION something very long.. now at least the program runs and outputs a correct output. yet still got this problem..

Comment: That doesn't sound like a build error, but a run-time crash. That probably means you are using pointers incorrectly.

Comment: LENGTH OF ROW is of size 2 it is a constant. Size is a size received by user - which I use in valgrind - I start from size 1, then size 2  then size 4 then size 8 then size 16 until all data is inside the table.

Comment: So `size` is never really uninitialized? Is it possible to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That would help us very much!

Comment: I've added where I receive the size and also added createTable

Comment: `sscanf(argv[1], "%d",(&tableSize));` is wrong when `sizeof(int)  != sizeof(size_t)`. use `%zu` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That is probably the problem. Had OP used any flags he would have been be warned.